# Radio button is not changing the value once I am clicking first time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have 3 radio buttons and it's by default is selected as YES and I have one submit button. If I will select any one as no button then submit button will disable. Once every three button is yes then save button enable otherwise disable.

I have below code written in my project.

```js
app
  .controller(
    "MainCtrl",
    function($scope, $http) {
      $scope.formModel = {
        internationalClient: 0,
        isConfidential: 0,
        isModificationLossRecog: 0,
        idenComplianceForFinDifficulty: 1,
        idenComplianceForConcession: 1,
        idenComplianceForModificationOrRefin: 1
      };

      $(".radioBtn")
        .click(
          function() {
            $("#save").attr("disabled", true);

            $scope.forbraranceJson1 = angular.toJson(
              $scope.formModel, false);
            console.log($scope.forbraranceJson1);
            var x1 = JSON.parse($scope.forbraranceJson1);

            console.log("11 " + x1.idenComplianceForModificationOrRefin);
            console.log("22 " + x1.idenComplianceForFinDifficulty);
            console.log("33 " + x1.idenComplianceForFinDifficulty);
            if (x1.idenComplianceForModificationOrRefin == 1 && x1.idenComplianceForConcession == 1 && x1.idenComplianceForFinDifficulty == 1) {
              $("#save").attr("disabled", false);
              $scope.measureCheckbomsg = "";
            } else {
              //$("#save").attr("disabled", true);
              $scope.measureCheckbomsg = "Please select all Forbearance requirements as YES";
            }
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<html ng-app="App">

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form name="theForm" novalidate="novalidate">

    <input type="radio" ng-model="formModel.isModificationLossRecog" ng-value="1">Yes
    <input type="radio" ng-model="formModel.isModificationLossRecog" ng-value="0" ng-checked="true">No


    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" ng-model="formModel.idenComplianceForFinDifficulty" ng-value="1" ng-checked="true">Yes
    <input type="radio" ng-model="formModel.idenComplianceForFinDifficulty" class="radioBtn" ng-value="0">No

    <input type="radio" ng-model="formModel.idenComplianceForConcession" ng-value="1" class="radioBtn" ng-checked="true">Yes
    <input type="radio" class="radioBtn" ng-model="formModel.idenComplianceForConcession" ng-value="0">No

    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" id="save" ng-click="saveRegistration(theForm.$valid)">Save</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I click first time any radio button the value does not change 1 to 0 . If I will click a 2nd time then its value is changing in JSON.

Comment: first of all you are using $('') jquery. try avoid the click. and use the ng-change directive in the radio.

Comment: Thanks for help. I changed ng-change, now its working for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your sample, you should not use radio buttons but checkbox. Radio button is more use when you want a choice between several value. In you case it's more like a boolean so checkbox seems a better choice.

Then in angular use "ng event" like `ng-click` or `ng-change`

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="formModel.idenComplianceForConcession" ng-click="clickedCallback"/>
```

like that in your controller

```
$scope.clickedCallback = function () {
 console.log(formModel.idenComplianceForConcession);
}
```